# File name conversion for cloud storages?

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox

Lets say I have a web URL to a file on a cloud storage (like Dropbox, Google Drive, etc). How do I convert that to the corresponding file path on my pc? On Android? On iOS?

Assuming of course I have the utilities/apps installed locally.

**EDIT:** I interested in file name the reverse direction too. (I.e. when I have the local file path, what is the web path?)

**EDIT 2:** @Greg just made me realize that the problem with file name is much worse on Google Drive than on Dropbox.

And that is very bad. :-(

The reason? Google has good search capabilities on Drive and therefor I and many, many others have put their documents on Drive. However, once I found it I must locate it on my on computer/device. (If I want to edit a pdf for example.)

**EDIT 3:** @Dan McGrath kindly asked what parts remain unsolved. 
Short answer: All. ;-)
Long answer: My actual use case, see below.

*My actual use case is a [Zotero](http://zotero.org) web app.* Zotero is a reference database where you store references to scientific articles, web pages, etc. The items stored in Zotero may include PDF files or - which I prefer - links to PDF files.

I just want to be able to easy access (read) this PDF files from any computer through the web app. And on my own computer I want to be able to edit the files with my local PDF editor. (Be it Android, Windows or whatever.)

By using a cloud storage I do not have to download/upload the files myself. The cloud storage takes care of that part.

Comment: I can't speak to other, but Dropbox shared links don't offer an API for retrieving the full/original path of the linked file.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @jterrace. :-) That was a better tag.

Comment: Thanks @Greg. I hope you are not correct. :-( -- Do you know why they do not offer this?

Comment: I don't know why, just that it's not currently something that is implemented and available.

Comment: How do you know it is not available, @Greg? Are you very familiar with the API, or?

Comment: I'm a developer advocate at Dropbox (and I just sent this along as a feature request).

Comment: Hey Leo, if you are running the Drive sync client and use a Chrome Browser, you can actually open a file from the web UI directly in a local program: http://googledrive.blogspot.com/2014/11/launch-desktop-applications-from-google.html

Comment: That is good, @DanMcGrath, and solves a part of the problem on the desktop. But only a small part.

Comment: What other parts remain unsolved for your use case?

Comment: I updated the question, @DanMcGrath. Thanks for the reminder. I have not really got any closer to a solution at all yet. I am starting to believe that it is impossible to do this now. (I hoped for some SDK:s or similar.)

Answer (score 1):

For the "reverse" scenario, that is, you have a file and you want the Dropbox shared link, you can use this API endpoint, assuming you're connected to the account via the API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares

Comment: Thanks, that is good, but not what I am looking for. Both these paths are web URLs.

Comment: Not exactly, the /shares endpoint takes a `path` parameter as input, which is a path relative to the root of the Dropbox. E.g., to share a file in your Dropbox named "test.txt" in a folder called "Documents", you'd supply "/Documents/test.txt".

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is the same kind of problem. And that API seems useful. However in my case I want to convert between web URL and local machine file paths. But with your example you just made me realize that Google Drive is far worse than Dropbox here. From Drive I just see web URLs that looks like the shared URLs from Dropbox.